# Creating VPN client and server using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, vpn

I would like to create a VPN client and VPN server using WCF through HTTP.

Can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be transparent you will need to write a driver.  But if you just want a tunneling proxy it is easy enough to write.  If you use a Session Required Contract with a call back event you can build the tunnel.

Sorry I cannot provide a working example at this time.  But I will make a note to cleanup project I have and blog about it later.

**Edit...**

I took down the site with my example a few years back... if I remember I will track down the code and post it to github.

Comment: You are the best mate!! Thank You!! :-) Would be really nice if you could host this as an opensource in codeplex/sourceforge and provide  a bit if support too though ;)

Comment: That would mean I would have some form of support for it... it took me a month just to get it cleaned up to the pointed I could and wanted to share it with the world.  If anyone wants to turn it into a open source project... I won't stop you.

Answer (score 7):

WCF is for creating high-level web service applications, not low-level network system drivers, components, etc.

Of course, you can build web services in WCF that will run over a VPN, but you can't build VPN drivers in WCF.